# Multiple LLC's lawsuit question

Tags: united-states, business, liability

If you have a parent LLC that owns several other LLCs are you still protected. For instance if one of the child LLCs lands a lawsuit can that lawsuit effect your other LLC or the Parent LLC and you run the possibility of losing your other LLC's?

Comment: Affect the other LLCs in what way?

Comment: So with LLCs they protect your money and other belongings outside of the business. Would that also include your other LLCs?

Comment: sure. An LLC's assets can include other LLCs that it owns, but "sibling" LLCs owned by the same parent would normally be independent.

Comment: Example: LLC A owns LLC B and LLC C. LLC C gets sued. Could you potentially lose money or ownership from LLC B or LLC A?

Comment: I think not, but I'll leave a proper answer for someone more knowledgeable thanI.